# $(...).tooltip is not working since jQuery 1.9.2 is not working due to old jQuery UI 1.8.16 library? How to fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I'm working on a website which is built in some heavy PHP framework.

So it already has included **jQuery UI 1.8.16** library. Now I have to implement  `$(...).tooltip` functionality on one web page. This feature is not availabe in jQuery UI 1.8.16 but it is available in  **jQuery 1.9.2** .

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

So I included following line into the HTML file where I want to implement the  `$(...).tooltip` functionality. But still in firebug I got following error:

```
TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function
```

How to resolve this issue? Can someone please help me in this regard?

Comment: Are you able to upgrade the framework's version of jquery ui? It looks like 1.9 is backwards compatible with 1.8 so you should be safe. http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/

Answer (score 0):

You can download only *Tooltip* widget from [jQuery UI - Download Builder](http://jqueryui.com/download/).

To build a custom jQuery UI library, check the following items:

- **UI Core**

  1. Core
  2. Widget
  3. Position
- **Widgets**

  1. Tooltip
- **Theme** (optionl)

Then load JS library after jQuery core as well as stylesheets.

After that you can simply initialize the widget.

```
$( "#tooltip" ).tooltip();
```

[Here is a working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/1ujkm20s/)